# URLSession dataTask: POST request says can not connect to server, can access using POSTMAN

Tags: ios, post, urlsession

Probably something very silly, but scratching my head to find as to why this is happening. I have a small Flask REST server running locally on my machine and I am posting some JSON data. It's working correctly, when I check using POSTMAN, but when I invoke the POST using the following code, I get the error- Could not connect to server. What am I doing wrong, really? I checked, the URL is formed correctly.

```
    func postJSONPayload(payload: Data, completion: ((Error?) -> Void)?) {
    print("Posting JSON Payload to server........")
    var urlComponents = URLComponents()

    urlComponents.scheme = "http"
    urlComponents.host = "127.0.0.1"
    urlComponents.port = 5000
    urlComponents.path = "/mobir/api/payloads"

    guard let url = urlComponents.url else {fatalError("Could not create url from components!")}
    print("url is: \(url.absoluteString)")
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"


    var headers = request.allHTTPHeaderFields ?? [:]
    headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
    request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers

    request.httpBody = payload
    print("payload: ", String(data: request.httpBody!, encoding: .utf8) ?? "No payload in body!")


    let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let session = URLSession(configuration: config)

    let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { (responseData, response, responseError) in
        print("got the response!")

        guard responseError == nil else {
            print("responseError not nil- error is: \(responseError!.localizedDescription)")
            completion?(responseError!)
            return
        }

        if let data = responseData, let utf8repofData =
            String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
            print("response: ", utf8repofData)
        } else {
            print("No data to read in response!")
        }
    }

    task.resume()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, it was silly- answering on my own. Needed to put `app.run(host= '0.0.0.0')` in my Flask server code so that it's visible across the network when the URL contains the IP address of the machine. Works now.